# TabbedPage and Content pages are not showing

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.droid

I am fairly new to Xamarin and XML although I have experience with C#. I have created a tabbed page in xml and it isn't displaying at all **Main.axml**:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:mypages="clr-namespace:MainActivity.Pages;assembly=MainActivity"
            x:Class="MainActivity.tabPages">
  <TabbedPage.Children>

    <mypages:Home />
    <mypages:AddLocation />

  </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

I have 2 tabbedpage children (Home and Add Location) I want the Home page to be the default page, although even the TabbedPage won't show up and the app is blank.

**Home.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MainActivity.ActualPage" Title="Home" BackgroundColor="Green">
  <ContentPage.Content>

    <Label Text="Hi there from Page 1" TextColor="White" Font="20"
        VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainActivity.cs:**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Xonify
{
    [Activity(Label = "App", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        }
    }
}
```

[Project's Strucutre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z15G.png)

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Please post your complete code

Comment: Are you setting the `Main.xaml` (not axml) as the `MainPage` in the `App.xaml.cs`?

Comment: I added SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main); and it seems to have added it, although it is throwing the error Error inflating class TabbedPage

Comment: I have added the structure and code to the post

Answer (score 0):

Your MainActivity.cs isn't setup to support Xamarin Forms, its loading the view natively. Change your MainActivity.cs to this:

using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

```
namespace Xonify
{
    [Activity(Label = "App", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/MainTheme", Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new Xonify.PCL.App()); // Change to point to your App.xaml.cs class
        }
    }
}
```

You will also need to create a file call styles.xml in your Resources > Values folder and add this theme in.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <!-- You can change options in here, or change the parent style -->
  </style>
</resources>
```

If you want to see an example you can have a look at https://github.com/exrin/ExrinSample/blob/master/Exrin-Sample/ExrinSample.Droid/MainActivity.cs

Comment: Thanks, but my project doesn't even contain an App.xaml.cs file

Comment: Then create one, inherited from Application. Then assign the MainPage property a new instance of your MainPage. Create a new Xamarin Forms application from scratch if you want to see how its laid out. You have created just a stand alone Xamarin.Android app, not a Xamarin Forms one. The link to the example also contains an example of this if you want to look.