# The Type "name" was not found - Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implemenat a TabbedPage with Xamarin Forms. It is very similar to [TabbedPage and Content pages are not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43791117/tabbedpage-and-content-pages-are-not-showing)

However I have a quick question as to how to include other xaml files from the MainPage.xam:

Here is my code:
MainPage:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Assignment"
        x:Class="Assignment.MainPage">
<TabbedPage.Children>

    <local:Alarm /> "The type 'local:Alarm' was not found. Verify that you are not missing..."

</TabbedPage.Children>
```

The above error is the only build error.

Alarm.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Assignment.Droid.Resources.layout.Alarm">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is my project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

On the other link, I saw that he put his xaml files in the layout folder.

Is this the correct setup? I think I have missed something simple.

Comment: Just move `Alarm.xaml` to your shared code under `Assignment`. Take it out of Android resources

Comment: Like this? same error https://ibb.co/iZxwsp

Comment: Error even with `x:Class="Assignment"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Greggz mentions: move it to your shared project.

Then you will have to change your namespaces because that is what actually matters. In .NET land, it is customary that your namespace equals the path on your filesystem.

In you `Alarm.xaml`, change this line: `x:Class="Assignment.Droid.Resources.layout.Alarm"` to `x:Class="Assignment.Alarm"`.

Then go into your code-behind, the `Alarm.xaml.cs` file and change the namespace there too. So change `namespace Assignment.Droid.Resources.layout` to `namespace Assignment`.

Since the XAML and the code-behind are implemented as a partial class, this needs to be in sync.